# how to catch this 20140205101309 date format?

Tags: oracle

I wanna catch the date in my table which is written like this "20140205101309" I tried to get by many ways, but i was not able to catch it  so how to modifiy my query to catch it ?

```
select * from my.DETAIL a where A.DATE 
between to_DATE('YYYYMMDD hh24:mi:ss','28-dec-2013 12:00:00')
and to_date ('YYYYMMDD hh24:mi:ss','2-feb-2014 00:00:00');
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Your date is 28-dec-2013 12:00:00 or you write like 2013-12-28 12:00:00

Comment: in the table its written like this  "20140205101309"  and   i just wanna catch all recods between 28-dec-2013 and 2-feb-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a.call_date a date before comparing:

```
  select *
  from operation.reject_detail a
 where to_date(a.call_date, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') between
       to_date('28-12-2013 12:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
       to_date('02-02-2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' );
```

Assuming 20140205101309 is: 2014, februari, 5 10:13:09

If you are not interested in the time part do this:

```
  select *
  from operation.reject_detail a
 where to_date(substr(a.call_date,1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') between
       to_date('28-12-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') and
       to_date('02-02-2014','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: What is the data type of a.call_date? You can easily test that the to_date statement works:  select to_date('20140205101309','YYYYMMDDHHMISS') from dual

Comment: yea select to_date('20140205101309','YYYYMMDDHHMISS') from dual  works fine and the datatype of the column is varchar2(50)

Comment: Ok I see where you go wrong. The other to dates are wrong. 1 first the date then the format string. 2 date and format string don't match.
Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: uh nice job i wonder if there is away to skip the time part and just get the date part of the whole string ??

Comment: trunc(to_date(a.call_date, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')) and to_date('28-12-2013','DD-MM-YYYY')

Comment: alternatively: to_date(substr(a.call_date,1,8), 'YYYYMMDD')

Answer (score 1):

Storing dates as strings is bad practice, but since that is what you have and it's in a relatively sensible format, you can just compare it as a string:

```
select * from my.DETAIL a
where A.DATE between '20131228120000' and '20140202000000'
```

Or to ignore the time part on the table and include the full second date:

```
select * from my.DETAIL a
where A.DATE between '20131228000000' and '20140202235959'
```

There doesn't seem to be much point converting everything to `DATE` types, particularly if your column is indexed. If it isn't indexed than you could just look at the date part:

```
where substr(A.DATE, 1, 8) between '20131228' and '20140202'
```

Comment: yea thats was big misktake ummm ill try to find a way to re formats date at this column and then alter it to date datatype